# How to stop a label being duplicated with each item outputted in a WPF listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

this is my first time working with XAML. I am currently outputting a list of missings assets in my program, this is displayed on the UI using XAML and a grid within a listview. At the top of the list I just want some header saying that the following list is all the missing assets. But my issue is that for every item outputted in the list, it will display that header along with it, so the header ends up being outputted as many times as there are items in the missing assets list, here is my code for the listview

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,0,20"
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SelectionlessListViewItemStyle}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding MissingAssets}">
        <ListView.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ListView">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Style>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5,0,5,0">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="The following assets could not be found" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Is this to do with the property being a label? I tried changing it to a textbox too but the issue is still there.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean groups? Or just on top? Can't you move the label outside of grid?

Answer (score 0):

A ListView is a more sofisticated ListBox.

If you provide the header in the data template, it's the expected behavior because the data template is  used to render **each item**. That's why if you have a label in your data template, it will be repeated n times (n being the number of items in your items source).

If you want to provide headers in a ListView, [here is the Microsft documentation showing how](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listview?view=netframework-4.8).

Judging from your code, maybe all you want is to use a ListBox instead of your ListView and you can put the header above the ListBox element and remove the "header" from your data template but it may be oversimplified and you may have not given all your data template content.